# How does conversion check on partial elements/systems (in terms of cubical) work?

Tags: implementation, cubical-type-theory

In cubical, `hcomp` is sometimes normal form, and to conversion check two normal `hcomp` terms, we need to compare the partial elements. I use the syntax $[\phi_i ↦ u_i]$ for partial elements, where clauses are $\phi_1\mapsto u_1, \phi_2\mapsto u_2$, etc.. But how does it work? In particular, I am thinking about the below code (where I use $u=v$ for "conversion checking $u$ and $v$):

$[ \phi_i ↦ u_i ] = [ \psi_j ↦ v_j ]$ is like making sure $\bigvee_i \phi_i = \bigvee_j \psi_j$ and then what? I expect $∀ i, \phi_i \vdash u_i =$ something something, but how do I check them?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for $\forall i, j\quad \phi_i \wedge \psi_j\vdash u_i = v_j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the paper about Cubical Agda](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3341691) you may find that partial elements `Partial r A` “are equal whenever they reduce to equal terms for all the possible assignment of variables that make r equal to i1”.

Firstly you should ensure that these partials are correctly defined, i.e. for all $i$ and $j$ we have $\Gamma, \phi_i ∧ \phi_j ⊢ u_i \equiv u_j$ (see [CCHM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.02108.pdf), page 9, figure 3), but this should be performed earlier, while deducing type of $[\phi_i \mapsto u_i]$.

Then yes, you need to check that two partials are defined on equal `r`’s, i.e.  $\bigvee_i \phi_i = \bigvee_j \psi_j$ (otherwise they have different types).

What to do next depends on the way you store partials.

Assume that any $\phi_i$ is a face in the form $(\phi_i^1 = d_{\phi_i}^1)\ (\phi_i^2 = d_{\phi_i}^2)\ ...\ (\phi_i^k = d_{\phi_i}^k)$ (where $\forall m: d^m_{\phi_i} \in \{0,\ 1\}$), then $\bigvee_i\phi_i$ is equal to $1$ iff for some $i$ we have $\phi_i^m \equiv d^m_{\phi_i}$ for all $m$ (since $\bigvee_i\phi_i$ is a disjunction and each $\phi_i$ is a conjunction). We know at this point that $\bigvee_i \phi_i = \bigvee_j \psi_j$, so for some $j$ we have $\forall m: \psi_j^m \equiv d^m_{\phi_j}$. Then $[\phi_i \mapsto u_i]$ reduces to $u_i$ and $[\psi_j \mapsto v_j]$ to $v_j$. If we assume that each $u_i$ and $v_j$ does not contain any $\phi_i^m$ and $\psi_j^m$ respectively (otherwise you should replace in $u_i$ each $\phi_i^m$ with $d^m_{\phi_i}$ and each $\psi_j^m$ in $v_j$ with $d^m_{\psi_j}$ and probably perform some computations), then it remains perform conversion-check between $u_i$ and $v_j$. And this is what, for example, [cubicaltt does](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt/blob/master/Eval.hs#L928-L930). My checker also performs [the same thing](https://github.com/forked-from-1kasper/anders/blob/master/src/kernel/check.ml#L559) (`Map.equal` in OCaml checks for key equality too).

Of course, as Trebor said, we can check $\Gamma, \phi_i ∧ \psi_j ⊢ u_i \equiv v_j$ for all $i$ and $j$, but if partials are correctly defined and for each pair $\phi_i \equiv \psi_j$ we have $u_i \equiv v_j$, then assuming some $i$ and $k$ we have for some $j$ such equality: $\Gamma, \phi_i \equiv \psi_j ⊢ u_i \equiv v_j$. Since partials are defined correctly, we have $\Gamma, \psi_j ∧ \psi_k ⊢ v_j \equiv v_k$. Combining these, we obtain $\Gamma, \phi_i ∧ \psi_k \equiv \psi_j ∧ \psi_k ⊢ u_i \equiv v_j \equiv v_k $ and $ \Gamma, \phi_i ∧ \psi_k ⊢ u_i \equiv v_k $ for all $i$ and $k$. So it’s enough to conversion-check only $u_i$ and $v_j$ with equal $\phi_i$ and $\psi_j$.

But this is not the only one way to store partials. For example, if you don’t have diagonals (faces like $(i = j)$ for free $i$ and $j$), you may assume that each $\phi_i$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathrm{I}$, so $[i ∧ -j \mapsto u, k \mapsto v]$ corresponds to $[(i = 1) \mapsto u, (j = 0) \mapsto u, (k = 1) \mapsto v]$. Then on the second step you may convert $\bigvee_i \phi_i \equiv \bigvee_j \psi_j$ to DNF and iterate over conjunctions, looking for corresponding $u_i$ and $v_j$ for each conjunction.

You may also look at [cooltt](https://github.com/RedPRL/cooltt), which have some [fancy way to work with faces](https://github.com/RedPRL/cooltt/blob/main/test/com.cooltt#L13-L14) (pay attention at these `φ :`  and `i=r ∨ φ`).